# Changing the parameters of elements in a list individually

Tags: python, list

I want to change a parameters in a list of elements QF and QD as following:
Lattice is a list includes these elements for example :

```
lattice = [QF, QD, QF, QD]
```

And the indexes of these elements in the list are given in quad_indexes.

QF and QD has two parameters (K and FamName):

```
QF.K = 1.7 and QD.K = -2.1
QF.FamName = 'QF'
QD.FamName = 'QD'
```

I want to gave the random value for the parameter K for each element individually

I tried:

```
    i =0
    Quad_strength_err =[]
    while(i < len(quad_indexes)):

         if(lattice[quad_indexes[i]].FamName == 'QF'):
              lattice[quad_indexes[i]].K *= (1 + errorQF*random())
              i += 1

         elif(lattice[quad_indexes[i]].FamName == 'QD'):
             lattice[quad_indexes[i]].K *= (1 + errorQD * random())
             i += 1
    
    for j in quad_indexes:
       quad_strength_err = lattice[j].K
       Quad_strength_err.append(quad_strength_err)
```

The problem is when i print (Quad_strength_err) i got fixed value for each of QF and QD, for example:

```
[1.8729820159805597, -2.27910323371567, 1.8729820159805597, -2.27910323371567]
```

I am looking foe a result for example:

[1.7729820159805597, -2.17910323371567, 1.8729820159805597, -2.27910323371567]

Comment: It isn't clear what result you actually wanted.

Comment: @ScottHunter I am looking foe a result for example:

[1.7729820159805597, -2.17910323371567, 1.8729820159805597, -2.27910323371567]

Comment: @ely66, still not clear about your goal. Can you give a minimal reproducible example ? We can't run your code since some data are missing and you didn't provide which random function you are using

Comment: have you checked your  generated random float is different

Comment: There is a lot if indirection in your data structure. Could it be that `lattice[0]` is an alias of `lattice[3]`? Actually, that's almost certainly the problem: the line `lattice = [QF, QD, QF, QD]` creates pointers to `QF` and `QD`, not copies.

Comment: @joains, Yes the lattice[0].FamName = 'QF' and also the lattice[0].FamName = 'QF'
But i want to treat each of them individually, how can i solve it ?

Comment: @ely66 See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TL;DR

You need to make copies of QF and QD - you're making aliases.

##### The problem

The problem is almost certainly due to aliasing.

When you initialize `lattice` with this line:

```
lattice = [QF, QD, QF, QD]
```

what you are doing is creating a structure with two pointers to `QF` and two pointers to `QD`.

In your loop, you then modify `QF` twice, once via `lattice[0]` and again via `lattice[2]`, and ditto for `QD`.

##### The solution

What you need to do is create copies, maybe shallow, maybe deep.

Try this option:

```
from copy import copy
lattice = [copy(QF), copy(QD), copy(QF), copy(QD)]
```

and if that still doesn't work, you might need a deepcopy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
lattice = [deepcopy(QF), deepcopy(QD), deepcopy(QF), deepcopy(QD)]
```

Or, a more compact version of the same code, just cause I like comprehensions:

```
from copy import deepcopy
lattice = [deepcopy(x) for x in (QF, QD, QF, QD)]
```

Comment: The solution works fine with deepcopy

Answer (score 2):

If your code is correct, you can't expect a different result for your first and third element of `lattice` (resp second and last), since it's (to simplify) the same element.

Using `id`, you can easily show that, `lattice[0]` and `lattice[2]` share the same id, therefore modifying `lattice[0]` will modify `lattice[2]`.

You can duplicate each object QF and QD to git rid of this behavior

Answer (score 2):

I tryed to build a working sample of your problem starting by building simple `QF` and `QD` classes :

```py
from random import random

class QF():
    def __init__(self):
        self.K =  1.7
        self.FamName = "QF"
        
class QD():
    def __init__(self):
        self.K =  -2.1
        self.FamName = "QD"
```

then I create the lattice with different instance of the classis by calling them with ()

```py
lattice = [QF(), QD(), QF(), QD()]
```

I think your mistake comes from this step as `QF` refers to the class it self and `QF` creats a brand new instance that you can modify separatly from the other one. For example if you do `QF.K = 3` and then `a = QF()`, `a.K` should return you `3`.

finally I apply some randomness using the `random` imported previously :

```py
for i in lattice:
    if i.FamName == "QF":
        i.K = (1 + errorQF*random())
    elif i.FamName == "QD":
        i.K = (1 + errorQD*random())
```

form which I get :

```py
print(*[i.K for i in lattice])

>>>> 1.148989048860669 0.9324164812782919 1.0652187255939742 0.6860911849022292
```